Minimum area of triangles of a trapezoid
Given the length and the position of one of the bases (named $a$ in my case) of a trapezoid and the length of one of its diagonals (named $d$ in my case), calculate the value of the length of the other base (named $x$ in my case) to minimize the area of the 2 triangles constructed by the intersection of the 2 diagonals and the 2 bases (see the photo).

I am stuck thinking about how to obtain the hight of the triangle $AOB$ as with it, I could calculate his area (dependent on $x$) and therefore the area of the other triangle $DOC$ as it is similar to $AOB$.

Wouldn't this be minimized if the height of the trapezoid is just $0$?

@vanderWolf Yes, I have to add that it is also given the position of both: the base and the diagonal. Not only the length

For given base size ($a$) and the diagonal $d$ you can have a trapezoid of zero height...

@vanderWolf Of course, that is why I added that the position of the diagonal is given also, to do not suppose that we are in that case

To avoid cnfusion with coordinates, let me denote the length of the upper base (unknow) $c$ (not $x$).
Assume that the lower base of the trapezoid is located at coordinates $(0,0$ to $(a,0)$ and the upper base is located at coordinates $(z-c,w)$ to $(z,w)$, then its length is $c$ (unknown) and the diagonal is $d=\sqrt{z^2+w^2}$ (given).
Writing the equations for the lines of the two diagonals, we can find the cooridinates of the intersections of them:
$$
y=\frac{w}{z}x=\frac{w}{z-c-a}(x-a)
$$
yielding
$$
x=\frac{za}{c+a},\quad y=\frac{wa}{c+a}.
$$
Hence double the area of the two triangles you mention is
$$
f(c):=a\times y+c\times(w-y)=\frac{wa^2}{c+a}+c\left(w-\frac{wa}{c+a}\right)
=\frac{(a^2+c^2)w}{a+c}
$$
Since
$$
f'(c)=\frac{w(c^2-a^2 + 2ac)}{(a + c)^2}
$$
changes the sign from minus to plus at $c=a(\sqrt2-1)$ (so $f$ achieves the minimum), this is your answer.

If the position of $d$ is also given (i.e. angle $\alpha$ fixed and corner $C$ known), the only free parameter is $x$ and the position of $D$. As the sketch suggests, the sum of the triangular areas is $f=ha/2+h'x/2$,
$$
2f=ha+h'x
$$
where $h$ and $h'$ are the altitudes of the triangles. $h+h'$ is known because that is the shortest distance of $C$ to side $a$, $h+h'=d\sin\alpha$.
$$
h'=d\sin\alpha -h.
$$
In a coordinate system where $A=(0,0)$, $B=(a,0)$, $C=(d\cos\alpha,d\sin\alpha)$,
$D=(D_x,d\sin\alpha)$, points on the diagonal from $B$ to $D$ have coordinates
$$
% \vec B+t(\vec D-\vec B)=\left( \begin{array}{c} a+t(D_x-a) \\ td\sin\alpha \end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{c} a-t\cos\beta \\ t\sin\beta \end{array}\right)
$$
where $0\le t$ measures the Euclidean distance to $B$.
The points on the diagonal from $A$ to $C$ have coordinates
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u\cos\alpha\\
u\sin\alpha\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $0\le u\le d$ is the Euclidean distance to $A$.
The intersection of the two diagonals is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u\cos\alpha\\
u\sin\alpha\\
\end{array}\right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{c} a-t\cos\beta \\ t \sin\beta\end{array}\right),
$$
a linear system of equations which gives
$$
t_i= a\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}, u_i=a\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
$$
h=u_i\sin\alpha = t_i\sin\beta = a\frac{\sin\beta \sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
$$
h'=d\sin\alpha-a\frac{\sin\beta \sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
at the intersection.
Because $C_y=D_y=d\sin\alpha$ marks the end point of the second diagonal, $d\sin\alpha = t_D\sin\beta$ marks the range $t_D=d\sin\alpha/\sin\beta$ at point $D$, so $D_x=a-t_D\cos\beta = a- d\sin\alpha \cot\beta$.
$$
x=C_x-D_x = d\cos\alpha - [a- d\sin\alpha \cot\beta].
$$
$$
2f = a\frac{\sin\beta \sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)} a + [a\frac{\sin\beta \sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}-d\sin\alpha]
[d\cos\alpha - a+ d\sin\alpha \cot\beta].
$$
To find a minimum we set the derivative $d(2f)/d\beta$ to zero:
$$
\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)\sin^2\beta}
[
2a^2\cos\beta\sin^2\beta\sin(\alpha+\beta)
-2a^2\sin^3\beta\cos(\alpha+\beta)
-ad\sin^2\beta\cos\beta\cos\alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)
$$
$$
+ad\sin^3\beta\cos\alpha \cos(\alpha+\beta)
+ad\sin^2\beta\cos\beta\sin\alpha \cos(\alpha+\beta)
$$
$$
-d^2\sin\alpha\sin^2\beta\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)
-d^2\sin\alpha\cos^2\beta\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)
+ad\sin\alpha\sin^3\beta\sin(\alpha+\beta)
]
=
0.
$$
$$
-d^2\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-2d^2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta+2a^2\sin^2\beta
-d^2\cos^2\alpha\sin^2\beta=0
$$
Expand trig. functions of sums and factorize:
$$
-\frac{d^2}{2}+\frac{d^2}{2}\cos[2(\alpha+\beta)]+a^2-a^2\cos(2\beta)=0
$$
$$
\frac{d^2}{2}(\cos[2(\alpha+\beta)]-1)=a^2[\cos(2\beta)-1].
$$
$$
\frac{\cos[2(\alpha+\beta)]-1}{\cos(2\beta)-1}=2a^2/d^2
$$
$$
\frac{2\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)-2}{2\cos^2(\beta)-2}=2a^2/d^2
$$
$$
\frac{\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)-1}{\cos^2(\beta)-1}=2a^2/d^2
$$
$$
\frac{\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin^2(\beta)}=2a^2/d^2
$$
$$
\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}=\sqrt{2}a/d
$$
$$
\sin\alpha\cot\beta +\cos\alpha =\sqrt{2}a/d
$$
Inserting this expression for $\cot\beta$ above yields
$$
x = a(\sqrt{2}-1).
$$
